# SQL Vertica, Cast Long issue

Tags: sql, vertica

I have the following SQL statement

```
 cast('long', ((substr(D.business_day, 1, 4)||substr(D.business_day, 6, 2))||substr(D.business_day, 9, 2))) AS bdate_id_yyyymmdd,
```

I have tried to change the `'long'` to integer to see if that would work.

```
cast(integer, ((substr(D.business_day, 1, 4)||substr(D.business_day, 6, 2))||substr(D.business_day, 9, 2))) AS bdate_id_yyyymmdd,
```

Also tried  `integer(8)`

getting error:

```
Error: [Vertica][VJDBC](4856) ERROR: Syntax error at or near ","
SQLState:  42601
ErrorCode: 4856
```

Comment: [according to the manual](https://my.vertica.com/docs/9.0.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/LanguageElements/Operators/DataTypeCoercionOperatorsCAST.htm%3FTocPath%3DSQL%2520Reference%2520Manual%7CSQL%2520Language%2520Elements%7COperators%7CData%2520Type%2520Coercion%2520Operators%2520(CAST)%7C_____0) Vertica uses standard SQL cast: `cast(expresion AS data type)`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name , tried `cast(expression AS integer` but same error

Answer (score 0):

It's not only a syntax error. Vertica is relatively pecky at data types, too.

So you want to make an integer consisting of `yyyymmdd` from something that looks like an ISO date.

A string?

A date?

There are two ways to go about that. You can't SUBSTR() on a date; you can't call a function getting the day, month, or year, number, from an ISO formatted string.

This example illustrates what you can do. Remember, extracting integers from dates is faster than working with strings and substrings. If your `business_day` is a DATE type, do what I do with `business_date` below.

Oh, and Vertica also supports this syntax:

`<expression>::INTEGER`

to cast to integer.

Happy playing ...

Marco

```
WITH
d(business_date,business_day) AS (
          SELECT DATE '2018-03-04',  '2018-03-04'
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '1957-04-22',  '1957-04-22'
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '1959-09-27',  '1959-09-27'
)
SELECT
  CAST(
         substr(d.business_day, 1, 4)
       ||substr(d.business_day, 6, 2)
       ||substr(d.business_day, 9, 2)
    AS int
  ) AS with_substr
, (  YEAR (business_date)*10000
   + MONTH(business_date)*100
   + DAY  (business_date)
  ) AS with_calc
FROM d;

with_substr|with_calc
 20,180,304|20,180,304
 19,570,422|19,570,422
 19,590,927|19,590,927
```